# Sort on clicking table header

Tags: angularjs

I have a table populated with data and added a extra column to the existing table which is the division of two fields. I want to sort the newly added column on header click. I have created a function to calculate the division of two fields.

```
<table>
   <th >
        <a href="" style="color:#ffffff" ng-click="orderByField='test(event.Home_Sales_Price, event.Total_Home_Area_SqFt)';reverseSort = !reverseSort"> Home Sales By Total SF 
   </th>
   <tr ng-repeat="x in y>
   <td>{{test(x.some_value, x.sample_value)}}</td>
</table>
```

test function calculates division of passed two values. When i click on newly added header i can sort only on first click. when i click the header again it is not sorting how can sort the table data on clicking header.

Comment: angular-smart-table has this feature built in

Answer (score 1):

Check this URL 
http://plnkr.co/edit/arkCZcfXTIsW7sFCxisn?p=preview

It was written for a different question of mine but demonstrates how you can sort by clicking the headers.

```
$scope.SetSort = function (objName) {
        $scope.predicate = objName;
        $scope.reverse = !$scope.reverse;
    };
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this may not answer your question on how to do it, but there are a number of modules that have solved that problem, and may provide you with more than ordering functionality that you may wish to use to enhance your table. For example filters.

Check out the following modules:

#### ng-table

- [ng-table on Github](https://github.com/esvit/ng-table)
- [ng-table Example](http://bazalt-cms.com/ng-table/)

#### ui-grid

- [ui-grid Example](http://ui-grid.info)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're looking for [Angular filters](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/filter).

Answer (score 0):

Please check https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy for sorting based on table.